# How to let an image resize with the cursor in the middle using css?

Tags: javascript, css, layout, drag-and-drop, draggable

I use a drag and drop function and when i drag a image to an other div it resizes the image, see code below. But it resizes to the left corner in relation to the original image so the cursor and image are on a different spot which is confusing for the users. Is there a way to let the image resize and keep the position relative to the cursor, or center the image with the cursor in the middle?

This is the CSS code i use now:

```
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack div ul li.stack span label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 255px;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack div ul li.stack span label img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 255px;
    visibility: visible;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack .Group li.stack span.rank {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.Skin .PGR .DragAndDrop .stack div.Group ul li span img {
    width: 177px;
```

Comment: Did my solution help you out? If it wasn't clear enough, all you would do is tie the updatePosition() function to the drag/drop event. I tested it out this morning and it worked fine for me, hope it does for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, something like this should work. Basically, you just need to get the mouse coordinates then set the position of the image to the mouse coordinates minus half the width/height to center it. Hope this helps!

```
 window.onload = track;
 var mouseX, mouseY;
 function track() {
     if (window.Event) {
          document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
     }
     document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;
  }

 function getCursorXY(e) {
     mouseX = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
     mouseY = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
 }

 function updatePosition() {
      var img = document.getElementById('myimage'); 
      var width = img.clientWidth;
      var height = img.clientHeight;

      img.style.position = "absolute";
      img.style.top = mouseY-(height/2);
      img.style.left = mouseX-(width/2);
 }
```